# $ L = \{xyyz\in\{0,1,2\}^{*} : y \neq \epsilon \wedge \exists_{a \in \{0,1,2\}} |y|_a \equiv 0 \}$

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions, check-my-answer

$ L = \{xyyz\in\{0,1,2\}^{*} : y \neq \epsilon \wedge \exists_{a \in \{0,1,2\}} |y|_a \equiv 0  \}$

I think this languages is regular. I write regular expression:
            $(1 + 2 + 0) ^ {*} (11 + 22 + 1212 + 2121) (1 + 2 + 0) ^ {*} \cup (1 + 2 + 0) ^ {*} (11 + 00+ 1010 + 0101) (1 + 2 + 0) ^ {*} \cup (1 + 2 + 0) ^ {*} (00 + 22 + 0202 + 2020) (1 + 2 + 0) ^ {*}$

Can someone check out my answer?

Comment: It looks like you have an endless stream of interesting questions on regular-languages. Can you add a link to your source _in the question_?

Comment: @Apass.Jack There is no source/link. These are exam tasks from previous years, so I want to do them well. That's why i have so many question because I want solve this kind of task. Do you think my regular expression is good? It is L1 union L2 union L3 so i think languages L is regular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slight more formally, we have 
$$ L = \{xyyz : x,y,z\in\{0,1,2\}^{*} \wedge y \neq \epsilon \wedge \exists_{a \in \{0,1,2\}}\,|y|_a = 0  \}$$

Yes, your regular expression is correct. It can be made simpler.

$(0+ 1 + 2) ^ {*} (00 + 11 + 22 + 0101 + 1010 + 0202 + 2020 + 1212 + 2121)(0 + 1 + 2) ^ {*}$